# Are there any disadvantages to having two WSUS servers?

Tags: sql-server, updates, windows-users

We currently have 1 x workstations WSUS server and we want to bring in the patching of 9 x 2008 R2 servers which host our Citrix estate.

Would it be beneficial to have separate WSUS servers for workstation patching & server patching? 
Should we build a new one with a SQL Server DB instance rather than a WID for the new server?

We will be using Solarwinds Patchmanager for our software patching so we will be pointing that to the new WSUS server as well as our existing workstation WSUS server.

Any thoughts?

Comment: voted to move to superuser

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [sf] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions. Before posting there, think of a better way to phrase your question than *Any thoughts?*, which is extremely vague and broad in scope. It's a request for discussion rather than a specific question, and none of the [se] technical sites are for discussions. My thoughts are that if you post it as phrased now, it will very quickly get closed.

Comment: Agree with @KenWhite - I answered before I really thought about the venue, still learning the ropes.

Answer (score 0):

The are several considerations for designing your WSUS hierarchies.  Here's an overview, though this question may move to Super User.

- Administrative access.  Do you have different administrators for servers vs. workstations?  Separating the servers would prevent a workstation WSUS administrator from affecting your servers.
- Performance.  You mentioned 9 servers, but didn't mention how many workstations.  As long as CPU, disk, and networking are sufficient for your workstations, 9 more clients are unlikely to reach a tipping point.  If your servers are significantly in a different geographic reason, you may want to host the WSUS server more locally and potentially use an upstream/downstream relationship for central reporting and administration.
- Disk space. Adding Server updates will take significantly more disk-space for the content than the workstation content.  Do you have enough space for both, assuming you're hosting the content locally?  This is especially true if you also use the partial binaries option.
- Complexity of management. Two servers are double the moving pieces. Consider putting them into a tiered upstream/downstream relationship for ease in administration and reporting.

SQL Server vs. WID is affected by most of the above factors, as well as being primarily affected by your back-up strategy if you have one.  SQL Server licensing is also a matter, whereas the Windows Internal Database (WID) is a free option within the operating system.